# AWS Boto3 No Credential Error IAM role K8S

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, kubernetes, boto3, amazon-iam

I have a python script in our K8s cluster that is run as a k8s Cronjob every few minutes. The script checks the nodes in the cluster and if a node is unhealthy for more than 5 minutes, it terminates the node.
To connect to AWS I use Boto3.
requirement.txt

```
boto3==1.16.11
botocore==1.19.11
```

and the permissions are passed as pod annotations.

```
Annotations:  iam.amazonaws.com/role: arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/k8s-nodes-monitoring-role
```

The IAM role has `arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2FullAccess` policy and a valid trust policy.

```
{
   "Version": "2012-10-17",
   "Statement": [
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
  },
  "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
},
{
  "Sid": "",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
    "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::123456789:role/nodes.my-domain.com"
  },
  "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
}
]
}
```

The problem that I facing is that on some occasions the script throws `NoCredentialsError('Unable to locate credentials')` error. This behaviour is not consistent as on most occasions the script has successfully terminates the unhealthy node and I can cross-check it against AWS CloudTrail events.
I can see in kub2iam logs that the Get request receives 200 but the Put request receives 403.

```
ime="2020-12-21T12:50:16Z" level=info msg="GET /latest/meta-data/iam/security- 
credentials/k8s-nodes-monitoring-role (200) took 47918.000000 ns" req.method=GET 
req.path=/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/k8s-nodes-monitoring-role 
req.remote=100.116.203.13 res.duration=47918 res.status=200
time="2020-12-21T12:52:16Z" level=info msg="PUT /latest/api/token (403) took 19352999.000000 
ns" req.method=PUT req.path=/latest/api/token req.remote=100.116.203.14 
res.duration=1.9352999e+07 res.status=40
```

Any help or idea about how to debug this will be highly appreciated.

Comment: There is some drama related to IMDSv2 [in #241](https://github.com/jtblin/kube2iam/issues/241); do you have a newer version than that, and have you already followed their troubleshooting steps?

Answer (score 1):

I dont know kube2iam in detail, but maybe you should switch to a AWS native way called IRSA (IAM Roles for Service Accounts). You can find all necessary information in this blog post: https://aws.amazon.com/de/blogs/opensource/introducing-fine-grained-iam-roles-service-accounts/

Comment: thanks, will look into it and provide update.